# 8 or more authors with apacite does not show correctly in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I have seen from several sources that with `apacite`, entries with `N` authors -- where `N>7` -- should have their authors listed as follows in the bibliography:

> author1, author2, author3, author4, author5, author6, ... authorN

However, latex generates this:

> author1, author2, author3, author4, author5, author6 et al.

Notice the difference at the end.

Is there an option to easily change this or is it a more complex operation?

Edit: The bibliography style is called `apacite`.

Comment: Please indicate the name of the bibliography style file you use. There are several style files out there that implement apa-like reference and citation formatting...

Comment: The style itself is called apacite.

Comment: @Mico I guess that, given the additional information, you can answer this one.

Comment: @lockstep: Just got back from a business trip and managed to post a detailed answer (including an MWE) to the OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

I am unable to reproduce the faulty behavior you describe. Are you maybe using an older (read, obsolete) version of either `apacite.sty` or `apacite.bst`? Both files were given extensive updates as recently as February 2012; be sure to update your TeX distribution to include the latest updates to these (and many other) files.

For completeness, here's an MWE (minimum working example) that shows that the current version of `apacite` (version 6.01) implements the citation method prescribed by the 6th edition of the APA manual correctly; note that the book has 15 [!] authors but that only the first six and the very last one are listed in the references; the citation itself, of course, does the usual "FirstAuthor et al" thing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{squamlake.bib}
@book{squamlake:2010,
  author      = "Kenneth R. French and Martin N. Baily and John Y. Campbell and
                John H. Cochrane and Douglas W. Diamond and Darrell Duffie and
                Anil K. Kashyap and Frederic S. Mishkin and Raghuram G. Rajan
                and David S. Scharfstein and Robert J. Shiller and Hyun Song
                Shin and Matthew J. Slaughter and Jeremy C. Stein and Ren{\'e}
                M. Stulz",
  title       = "{The Squam Lake Report: Fixing the Financial System}",
  publisher   = "Princeton University Press",
  address     = "Princeton NJ and London",
  year        = 2010,
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\begin{document}
As argued by \citet{squamlake:2010}, \ldots
\bibliography{squamlake}
\end{document}
```

[image]